# How can I disable go back in some activity and not in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Basically when BACK button is pressed on the phone, I want to prevent a specific activity to return to its previous one in android.

Specifically, I have login and sign up screens, both start a new activity called HomeScreen when successful login/signup occurs. Once HomeScreen is started, I want to prevent the users to be able to return login or sign up screens with pressing BACK key also I want them to be able to navigate between fragments in HomeScreen e.g They can navigate to fragments like share,communicate etc.

I thought of using finish() method on backKey pressed but that would exit an application and I don't want that too.

Comment: Just finish activity that launches HomeScreen activity, so it becomes first in stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
public void onBackPressed() {

   if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
   } else {
        finish();
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Call finish() where you start the HomeScreen Intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreen.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: My code is like this:
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
          int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1;
           if (count == 0) {

            super.onBackPressed();

        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
}
 




That is working fine but when I successfully log in from signIn or SignUp activity and navigte to HomeScreen and press back key ,It returns me to  signIn or SignUp activity and I just want to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say this is the flow of your Activity

> SplashActivity----->HomeScreenActivity

**1) Remove SplashActivity from BackStack**

> SplashActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeScreenActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

**2) Override onBackPressed() in the HomeScreenActivity**

**Don't call** `super.onBackPressed()` when you override this method because default implementation calls finish() method internally.

> HomeScreenActivity.java

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();    <-- Dont call this 

   /* Your logic to navigate between fragments goes here */
}
```